# PHP/SQL: Inserting $row['id'] into a new table with PHP is inserting all row IDs, not just one

Tags: php, sql, join, insert

I have a system where you'll click a link to insert two pieces of data into a table. There are multiple images with links next to them.

So basically:

1) User logs in, images are retrieved from the database as blobs.

2) Clicks a "use coupon" button

3) Code uses a JOIN query to add the coupon ID and current user ID to a database.

4) Code will display all coupon images that haven't been used.

If I manually add the coupon ID and User ID to the database, it works perfectly fine and only displays the unused coupons. However, I have two issues. Only the last images button is working. If I have 3 images listed, only the button on the 3rd image works. On top of that, the button is removing all images, not just the single image corresponding to the $row['id'].

```
<?php

$coupons = mysqli_query($link, 
"SELECT coupons.*
FROM coupons
LEFT JOIN deleted_coupons ON
  deleted_coupons.coupon_id = coupons.id AND
  deleted_coupons.user_id = {$_SESSION['act']}
WHERE deleted_coupons.coupon_id IS NULL"
);

if (isset($_GET['del_task'])) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO deleted_coupons (coupon_id, user_id) VALUES ('{$row['id']}', '{$_SESSION['act']}')";
    mysqli_query($link, $sql); 
}

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($coupons)) { 

    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['id'] ?>
        <td class="task">
        <?php
        echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['name'] ).'"/>';
        ?>
        </td>
        <td class="delete"> 
            <a href="welcome.php?del_task=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">Use Coupon</a> 
        </td>
    </tr>

    <?php 
    }
?>
```

I have a feeling it has something to do with the way my insert query is inside the loop but I can't figure out what exactly is wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You're trying to insert `$row['id']` which doesn't exist. You probably want `$_GET['del_task']` in a prepared statement.  Also, the select should probably come after the insert or you will not get the most recent inserted one.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Why exactly does it work then on the last image? If I click the last image button, it does indeed add everything I want to the database including the row ID. The only problem is it adds everything, not just the one image (so it removes every image from my page, not just the one I want to remove). On top of that, my echo $row['id'] works perfectly and displays the row ID's next to the images